# Tor Exit Node Not connecting

Tags: tor

I have two internet connections one running a Tor Exit Relay and one just trying to connect using it. The exit relay port is 14569 I can't seem to connect using my exit relay Tor says everything is set up and working properly on the server end but the client end refuses it

This is my client configuration on the Non Exit Relay Tor

```
ExitNodes <server fingerprint>
StrictNodes 1
```

Do I need to specify a port for the exit relay?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to stop what you're trying to do entirely. Using your own exit node is a [great way to compromise your security](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit).

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that in the link you posted. The closest I could find was this quote in that faq section:
"... overriding the entry / exit nodes can mess up your anonymity in ways we don't understand." 
Looks like they don't know of any actual vulnerabilities and are only suggesting not to use it because someone in the future may possibly come up with a method to reduce your anonymity.